# How do I get my button to go through it's code again after clicking it once already?

Tags: c#, button

I have a button in my application that is a submit button. This button is supposed to verify the card number entered in the form.

After the third wrong entry the application is supposed to end. All of the necesssary code is there. But when I run it and I put an error in there on purpose, the message box will show, but then when I fix the text box and click the submit button again, nothing happens.

How can I get the button to work again?

```
private void submitOrderButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    counter += 1;

    string cardFirstFour = verifyTextBox.Text;

    if (counter <= 3)
    {
        if (verifyTextBox.TextLength == 1298 || verifyTextBox.TextLength == 12765 || 
            verifyTextBox.TextLength == 4512 || verifyTextBox.TextLength == 4567 && 
            verifyTextBox.TextLength == 8901 || verifyTextBox.TextLength == 8933)
        { 
            if (verifyTextBox.TextLength == 4 || cardTextBox2.TextLength == 4 || 
                cardTextBox3.TextLength == 4 || cardTextBox4.TextLength == 4)
            { 
                if (securityCodetextBox.TextLength == 3)
                { 
                    if (DateTime.Now.Month < monthNumericUpDown.Value && 
                        DateTime.Now.Year < yearNumericUpDown.Value)
                    {
                        Hide();
                        confirmation.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else if (counter > 3)
                    {
                        this.Hide();
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid card info: Too many wrong entries. Order canceled", "Invalid Entry",
                               MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Invalid card info: Check your card and try again.", "Invalid Entry",
                        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should have a TextChanged event on the textbox that resets `counter` to 0. I'm not sure why you'd allow the user to submit the same invalid card information 3 times in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your `if` conditions are correct.

You have this

```
if (counter <= 3) {
    ...
    else if (counter > 3)
    ...
}
```

So the `else if` condition above will never be reached. You should structure it like this:

```
if (counter <= 3) {

} else if (counter > 3) {

}
```

Also I would be more specific and rename `counter` to `invalidCounter` and only increment it when the information is invalid, not on every button click.

Comment: Oh! ok! That makes sense!